# Create unique set of maps in Dart

Tags: dart

I need to create a unique set of maps but it seems that adding maps to a set doesn't filter and adds duplicates.

```
Set mySet = Set();

List myList = [
  {"name": "Jane"},
  {"name": "Jane"},
  {"name": "Mary"}
]

for(var item in myList){
  mySet.add(item);
}
```

Doing this causes the set to contain all three maps. Is there any way to only have one `Jane`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than doing what @Patrick suggested, you also have to major ways:

1. If your map is constant just declare it as a `const` so they will reference always the same object, hence the Set will work as you expect to:

```dart
List myList = const [
  {"name": "Jane"},
  {"name": "Jane"},
  {"name": "Mary"}
]
```

2. Check if a map with the same name already exists before adding the new one:

```dart
  for(var item in list){
    // If a map with the same name exists don't add the item.
    if (set.any((e) => e['name'] == item['name'])) {
      continue;
    }
    set.add(item);
  }
```

Just a quick note, you can initialize a `Set` using its literal constructor *(there is a [linter rule](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_collection_literals.html) about this)*:

```dart
var set = <Map<String, String>>{}
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the second solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the Maps are different: `{"name": "Jane"} != {"name": "Jane"}`.

You have to create your own class and override `==` (and `hashCode`).

See "Implementing map keys":
https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour

Comment: I haven't done anything like that yet. Do you have an example, or a link where this is explained?

Comment: @William I added a link.